# Ways to make stop audio and play new one while it's playing by clicking the text

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, audio, audio-player

I linked between each of the musics and texts to make simple music player like this;

txt        audio
song1 - music1
song2 - music2
song3 - music3
song4 - music4

And what I want to make it is, if I click song1 while song2 is playing, stop song2 and play song1 from the beginning. If I click song3 while song4 is playing, stop song4 and playing song3 just like a real music player.

Sorry for my dumb question but is there any tips about this? Would be great if I have some infos from here to improve my js skills.

```js
let count = 0;

function playbutton1() {
  let song1 = document.getElementById("music1");
  count++;
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    song1.pause();
  } else {
      song1.play();
  }
}

function playbutton1() {
  let song3 = document.getElementById("music2");
  count++;
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    song3.pause();
  } else {
      song3.play();
  }
}

function playbutton1() {
  let song3 = document.getElementById("music3");
  count++;
  if (count % 2 == 0) {
    song3.pause();
  } else {
      song3.play();
  }
}

song1.addEventListener("click", playbutton1);
song2.addEventListener("click", playbutton2);
song3.addEventListener("click", playbutton3);
```

```html
<audio id="music1">
  <source src="song1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="music2">
  <source src="song2.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="music3">
  <source src="song3.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
<audio id="music4">
  <source src="song4.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Good first question, welcome to SO! For starters, your JS tries to add event listeners to `undefined` variables. Try moving your `let song2 = document.getElementById("music1");` outside of your functions.

Comment: @ggorlen Thx for comment and welcoming me here. I put the song2 line to outside of the functions and the song stops to come out. Maybe I shall try to fix the inside of functions.

Comment: That's another problem that can be handled, but the first problem is `undefined.addEventListener()` which is going to crash every run. BTW, please keep the `. . .` removed from your snippets. That causes them to be unrunnable.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for answering again. After I remove my `. . .` marks from my question, I found and fixed it `undefined.addEventListener()` error by changing `let song2 = document.getElementById("music1")` to `let music1 = document.getElementById("music1")`.